# Custom Rails route after object creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, custom-routes

**Update**: Instead of

`@company = Company.find(params[:company_id]` in the `Reimbursements New Action`

I used `@company = Company.find_by_name(params[:company_id]`

This replaced the `id` in the URL with the `name` but still requires `/reimbursements/new` at the end of the URL. Any thoughts?

**Overview**: I have a `Companies` controller/model and a `Reimbursements` controller/model

A `Company has_many reimbursements`

A `Company` has a `name` as well

**The Issue:**
When a new company is created the link to the new `reimbursements` form is

```
localhost:3000/companies/:id/reimbursements/new
```

This URL is very long and I would prefer it be:

```
localhost:3000/companies/company.name
```

Is this possible? How would I go about doing this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use whatever you want. Routes are just regular expressions. However the real question is if it is a good idea. Short url's are a marketing fad.

Comment: Can you please checkout the Update I posted? I would appreciate any insight

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add a permalink field in Company Model.

Then use routes as

```
localhost:3000/companies/:permalink/reimbursements/new
```

Now in controller, find Company be permalink instead id Id.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be

`get /companies/:name => reimbursements#new`

Rails defaults to making the route to a certain controller action the first route to that action it sees so make sure you put this above any routes that might override it (i.e. any reimbursements routes you might have). As Max suggested though, this isn't great form and the companies id wouldn't be passed through params with this structure

Comment: Your method did not work for me. Can you please checkout the update I posted?

Comment: What about it didn't work? also is `Company.find_by_name(params[:company_id])` definitely working? It looks like you're telling AR to search for something by a name and giving it an id